# More than 15000 parse tokens have been presented

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java, netflix-dgs

I am using **Spring Boot** with **Netflix DGS (GraphQL)** frameworks. I need to mutation my type which is big "Object" with recursive binding. When I want to use mutation, the DGS framework responses me with this error message:

```
More than 15000 parse tokens have been presented. To prevent Denial Of Service attacks, parsing has been cancelled. offending token ':' at line 1 column 97831
```

It is possible to increase this limitation by some configuration ideally maybe in **application.yml**, or in some **GraphQL** config?

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is related to this change: https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/pull/2549

New limits have been introduced to GraphQL.

You can use `graphql.parser.ParserOptions;` to set a higher maxTokens value.

Answer (score 1):

There is a by-default limit set of maxTokens as **15000**, you can change it using below configuration:

```
ParserOptions.setDefaultParserOptions(ParserOptions.newParserOptions().maxTokens(<YOUR_NEW_VALUE>).build());
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @rahul-tiwari and @bertkoor, this is related to a change in graphql-java that adds a new token limit for DOS protection.

In order to change this limit within the Netflix DGS framework, you can implement `GraphQLContextContributor` ([docs](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/advanced/graphqlcontext-leveraging/)) to set `ParserOptions`.

```
@Component
public class MyGraphQLContextContributor implements GraphQLContextContributor {

  @Override
  public void contribute(
      @NotNull GraphQLContext.Builder builder,
      @Nullable Map<String, ?> extensions,
      @Nullable DgsRequestData dgsRequestData) {

    ParserOptions parserOptions = ParserOptions.newParserOptions().maxTokens(1_000_000).build();
    ParserOptions.setDefaultParserOptions(parserOptions);
    builder.put(ParserOptions.class, parserOptions);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone like me stubling upon this, since graphql-java 18.3 / netflix.graphql.dgs 5.2.4 you need to call ParserOptions.setDefault**Operation**ParserOption.

Full code snippet which takes any existing options into account:

```
    ParserOptions.setDefaultParserOptions(ParserOptions.getDefaultParserOptions()
            .transform(opts -> opts.maxTokens(<YOUR_NEW_VALUE>)));
    ParserOptions.setDefaultOperationParserOptions(ParserOptions.getDefaultOperationParserOptions()
            .transform(opts -> opts.maxTokens(<YOUR_NEW_VALUE>)));
```